# how to get an input on textbox and display it on another textbox below

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i'm trying to create a simple app on google app script
i want that when a user will insert a value to one field
it will Immediately will be shown on the disabled textbox below as in the picture i've uploaded
this my code,its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <script>
       document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("input",Check);

       function Check(){      
          var Code = document.getElementById("one").value;
          document.getElementById("two").value = Code;
       }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    three:<input  type = "text" id="one"/>
    four:<input disabled type = "text" id="two"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

[textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6JZg.jpg)

Comment: Put script at last,... because Once HTML DOM element loaded then only we can able access in our scripts,... otherwise DOM element used in script will not accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
three:<input oninput='document.getElementById("two").value = this.value' type = "text" id="one"/>
four:<input disabled type = "text" id="two"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
firstval = document.getElementById("one").value;
secondval = document.getElementById("two").value = firstval
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTMLElement: input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

```js
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("input", updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
    document.getElementById("two").value = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
three:
<input type="text" id="one" />
four:
<input disabled type="text" id="two" />
```

And put the script at the end of body. Otherwise elements with id `one` and `two` will not be available while your script is running.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top" />
    </head>
    <body>
        three:
        <input type="text" id="one" />
        four:
        <input disabled type="text" id="two" />

        <script>
            document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("input", updateValue);

            function updateValue(e) {
                document.getElementById("two").value = e.target.value;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```